# Examples of widely-used software applications using user-level threads?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

Can somebody give me an example of  widely-used software applications that use user-level threads. Here by 'user-level' threads I mean threads that are implemented entirely in user-space and are unknown to the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I would say most web browsers IE, Firefox, Chromium/Chrome do so. For Chromium, a new user thread is created whenever you create a new tab.

Comment: I think Chrome creates a new *process* for each tab. It's unusual design, for sure.

Comment: Yep, just look at the list of running processes when having multiple tabs opened in Chromium.